# robot_state_publisher design: multiple publishers on /joint_states ok?

Tags: ros, robot-state-publisher, joint-states, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is robot_state_publisher designed to handle multiple sources of /joint_state information? For example, let's say I have the R2D2-like robot from this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher).
If I have one node publishing the state of the 'periscope' on `/joint_states`, and another node publishing the rest of the joints, also on `/joint_states`, will `robot_state_publisher` do the right thing? (i.e., 'merge' the `/joint_state` messages?).

I'm currently studying the source code to definitively figure this out, but I see that others have asked this in the past, so I figured I'd raise the issue again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270623/robot_state_publisher-design:-multiple-publishers-on-/joint_states-ok?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2017-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-09-10**:
I think this will work but I'm not certain.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-09-10**:
After looking at the source, I think so, too. I'll post my result after I get it working (or don't) :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
Yes. This is designed to work like this afaik.

An alternative could be to use `joint_state_publisher` with the `source_list` argument. It will merge all `JointState` msgs on the specified topics and publish a single representative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this definitely works, we've been using different robots with different nodes contributing to joint states and all getting fed into one robot_state_publisher for years.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
Minor perhaps, but @Rick Armstrong describes a setup where multiple `JointState` publishers feed a single `robot_state_publisher`. Having a single `joint_state_publisher` merge multiple `JointState` msgs into a single one (via `source_list`) is slightly different.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-09-12**:
Arg, I actually meant robot_state_publisher and mistyped. Fixed now.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2017-09-17**:
Side note for fellow dunces: if you forget to populate JointState.header.timestamp before publishing, robot_state_publisher will quietly drop your JointState messages (unless you set ignore_timestamp to true).